# Why Excel 2016 generate graphic errors?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, imac

On a 5k iMac with AMD Radeon R9 M380 I run Windows 10 with Excel 2016 last patch level. If I run a new Excel-Sheet in Fullscreen mode I get some graphic errors (grey cells) in right border of the Screen, it happens only in Fullscreen mode. A other Computer with the same specs doesn't produce the errors. How can I debug this kind of errors?

If I do a resize of the window than the errors don't appears. I think it is a driver issue but on the second 5k iMac there is no error. The error occurs on a external display without 5k too.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry I missed that originally

Answer (score 1):

You need to **disable Hardware Acceleration**:

Start any Office program.

On the File tab, click **Options**.

In the Options dialog box, click **Advanced**.

In the list of available options, click to select the Disable hardware graphics acceleration check box.

Reboot

Comment: To disable the Hardware Acceleration doesn't help.